# backbone.js bulk update

Tags: backbone.js

So I have a page in which a user is selecting from a list of available options via checkboxes.
I have 3 collections: One for possible list of options, one for the currently saved options, and a clone of the saved options. I am using the clone list to add/remove options as they click on checkboxes.

```
var possibleOptions = new Backbone.Collection("/options");   
var currentUserOptions = new Backbone.Collection("/useroptions", { id: 2 });
var clonedUserOptions = new Backbone.Collection(currentUserOptions.toJSON());
```

The reason this approach was taken is that a user can cancel out of the options page mid edit so want the options persisted upon clicking a save button. The clonedOptions are updated correctly as options are checked/unchecked. However, when I try to update the real list nothing seems to happen.

```
currentUserOptions.update(clonedUserOptions.toJSON());
```

My expectation was that backbone would trigger post request for the new models and deletes for each missing model according to the docs (http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Collection-update). Please let me know if I am misunderstanding how this is suppose to work. A simple working example of the right approach would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
CF

Comment: After updating `currentUserOptions` you still need to save them. Something like `currentUserOptions.each(function(item){ item.save(); });` might work, or at least a good start.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Paul, but what about options that have been deleted? They would no longer exist when doing currentUserOptions.each.

Comment: Hmm good point. `update` is not really meant to be used like this, it is more for updating your collection with data from the server.

Comment: Have you considered just using a model for the user options? Then you could just set attributes when checkboxes are clicked, `model.set({option1: true, option2: false});` and when save is clicked, `model.save();`.

Comment: You can use `reset` to add/delete the necessary models. You'll need to call `save` on those models then.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I will try a few different approaches and see how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

It is my understand that you have to update the server with individual model calls when the collection changes (as people have mentioned). There are events to cover these changes. However, you can send the entire collection using sync. When each model is added or removed you can flag it as new and deleted and when you are ready to save send the entire collection. Your server methods will have to take care of determining the appropriate add or delete operation then when the collection is sent.

Here is an example of doing a bulk sync. Instead of using this.collection.remove() you may just want to flag as deleted as I mentioned. This is pretty much the only way the server would know what to delete. Technically you could delete everything and then just add what is sent in the bulk update :) Also you might have to do another get or return a collection from the server when you save to update what has actually been removed. I am not sure this helps in your case, but I have used it for pages that "save when done" one button concept.

```
    var one = new model({ id: this.collection.length + 1});
    var two = new model({ id: this.collection.length + 2 });
    var three = new model({ id: this.collection.length + 3 });
    var four = new model({ id: this.collection.length + 4 });
    var five = new model({ id: this.collection.length + 5 });


    this.collection.add(one.toJSON());
    this.collection.add(two.toJSON());
    this.collection.add(three.toJSON());
    this.collection.add(four.toJSON());
    this.collection.add(five.toJSON());

    this.collection.sync('update', this.collection, { success: function () {    console.log(this.collection.length); } });

    this.collection.remove(one);
    this.collection.remove(two);

    this.collection.sync('update', this.collection, { success: function () { console.log(this.collection.length); } });
```

And in your case:

```
currentUserOptions.sync('update', currentUserOptions, { success: function () { //do something } });
```